# I dont understand how enum could be used here

Tags: c++, enums

I have been given a question for my programming course and I am struggling to see the purpose of enum in the question. if anyone could help me better understand this it would be much appreciated.

Write a program that gets the user's choice of colour strength and transparency.
Use a single enumeration for the colours and transparency - Red, Green, Blue and
Alpha.
Use a for loop that utilises the enumeration set to iterate from RED up to ALPHA
inclusive.
Inside the for loop get the user to enter avalue for each enumerated constant ( i.e. a
value for red, a value for blue, etc ). The values should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and
stored in an array.
Once all 4 values have been stored printout a summary of the values that the user

Comment: SO isn't going to do your homework for you! Show what you have tried already and which specific problems you have.

Comment: To get started, see e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44859/

Comment: i dont need any code written for me. just confused as to why I would use an enum here when the user needs to input a value for each colour anyway. or am i just reading the task wrong

Comment: i think i just figured it out anyway. the colours would correspond to the location in the array and could then call them up with array[RED]?

Comment: Looks like you need to read four values into an array - you can use the enumeration values as indexes into the array, instead of hard coded values like 0, 1, 2, 3 - this makes the code more robust and easier to read

Comment: Were the down votes necessary here? Seems like a legit question if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of the enum in this question is to test your understanding of this type and to asses your ability to utilize it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clearly expressed, so I'll help.  They're expecting that you'll use an enum like this:

```
enum RGBA { Red, Green, Blue, Alpha, Entries };

int value[Entries];

for (RGBA rgba = Red; rgba <= Alpha; rgba = RGBA(rgba + 1))
    ...read a user value into value[rgba]...
```